# Any one hit same compiling failed issue for Yocto project?

Tags: compiler-errors, yocto

I am a newer in Yocto, and tried build my project, but hit following issue, anyone hit same issue and comment on it?  Thanks a lot in advance.

> > > >
> > >       WARNING: /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/libwpe/libwpe_git.bb: Error during finalise of /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/libwpe/libwpe_git.bb
> > >       WARNING: /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/cog/cog_git.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for AUTOREV
> > >       WARNING: /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/wpebackend-fdo/wpebackend-fdo_git.bb: Exception during build_dependencies for AUTOREV
> > >       WARNING: /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/cog/cog_git.bb: Error during finalise of /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/cog/cog_git.bb
> > >       WARNING: /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/wpebackend-fdo/wpebackend-fdo_git.bb: Error during finalise of /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/wpebackend-fdo/wpebackend-fdo_git.bb
> > >       ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/meta-webkit/recipes-browser/libwpe/libwpe_git.bb
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >       bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable SRCPV, expression was ${@bb.fetch2.get_srcrev(d)} which triggered exception FetchError: Fetcher failure: Fetch command export PSEUDO_DISABLED=1; export PATH="/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/scripts:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/aarch64-oe-linux:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/sbin:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/sbin:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/work/aarch64-oe-linux/libwpe/1.0~git-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/bin:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/bitbake/bin:/local/mnt/workspace2/LE/CentOS_EDGE1.0/poky/build/tmp-glibc/hosttools"; export HOME="/usr2/shoudil"; git -c core.fsyncobjectfiles=0 ls-remote https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/libwpe.git  failed with exit code 128, output:
> > >       fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/WebPlatformForEmbedded/libwpe.git/': Failed to connect to 10.249.3.104 port 9090: Connection timed out
> > >       >

Appreciate and input for it. thanks again.
Shoudil

Comment: The IP address in the error message is in the local range: this sounds like a network or proxy setup issue in your end. Do you need a proxy to connect using git?

Comment: If yes, https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Working_Behind_a_Network_Proxy might be helpful

Comment: Actually, I have tried enable/disable proxy, but same error info reported.

Comment: Will follow up the wiki you provided and confirm it help or not, thanks a lot.

Comment: issue caused by unsuitable proxy setting in git config. resolved.